# Linq query working in LinqPad but not in VS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework

```
var rooms = tblRoom
        .Where(r => r.hotel_id==1)
        .GroupBy(p => p.tblType)
        .Select(g => new
            {
            TypeName = g.Key.type_name,
            TypeID = g.Key.type_id,
            TypeCount = g.Count()
            });

            rooms.Dump();
```

In LinqPad - this works fine, and returns:
[image: LinqPadScreenShot]

However, when I transfer this to Visual Studio:

```
var rooms = dbr.Rooms
                .Where(r => r.hotel_id == 1)
                .GroupBy(p => p.type_id)
                .Select(g => new 
                {
                    TypeName = g.Key.type_name,
                    TypeID = g.Key.type_id,
                    TypeCount = g.Count()
                });
```

I receive the message on the g.Key.type_name section:

**'long' does not contain a definition for 'type_name' and no extension method 'type_name' accepting a first argument of type 'long' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   **

I am trying to add the results to the following viewmodel:

```
    public class RatesViewModel
    {
        public string TypeName { get; set; }
        public long TypeID { get; set; }
        public int TypeCount { get; set; }
    }
```

I'm sure once again, it must be something simple I'm missing - so any help in getting the results into the view model, would be appreciated.

Thanks, Mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am trying to add the results to the following viewmodel:

I don't see how you are relating to this view model in your code. You are simlpy querying your repository and returning an anonymous object.

If you want to return a view model, adapt your query to project to this view model:

```
var rooms = dbr
    .Rooms
    .Where(r => r.hotel_id == 1)
    .GroupBy(p => p.type_id)
    .Select(g => new RatesViewModel
    {
        TypeName = g.Key.type_name,
        TypeID = g.Key.type_id,
        TypeCount = g.Count()
    })
    .ToList();
return View(rooms);
```

and now your view will obviously be strongly typed to the view model:

```
@model IEnumerable<RatesViewModel>
```

Comment: This is helpful, but doesn't solve the error message in the Linq code.

Comment: Hi Darin - thank you.  I should have said, I'm trying to return the data as part of an API - do I still use a viewmodel as above, to return JSON from the controller?  (it doesn't recognise View) - and return rooms(); advises the type ofnamespace name 'rooms' could not be found.  Thanks again, Mark

Comment: Please ignore me - I changed the start of the controller to be the same as the view model!  Thanks again for everyone's help.

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues. First, your LINQ Query is creating an Enumeration of Anonymous objects. You just need to modify your query to specify the type to solve that issue.

The next is that you're trying to assign the results of the query to a single object rather than an Enumeration of objects. To fix that issue, you just need to tack on a `First()` (or `Single()`, `FirstOrDefault()`, or `SingleOrDefault()` depending):

```
.Select(g => new RatesViewModel
{
    TypeName = g.Key.type_name,
    TypeID = g.Key.type_id,
    TypeCount = g.Count()
}.First()
```

Comment: Hi - you're correct - the group by should be: Type in the VS version.

Comment: @fixit - Then look at the second issue I have listed. That should take care of it.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the `GroupBy` lines in Linqpad vs. Visual Studio.  You are grouping by different things.

In the first, you are grouping by an object, but in the second you are grouping by a number.  The `Key` is the object being grouped, so calling `g.key.type_name` doesn't work when you are grouping by a number.

Comment: Hi - you're correct - the group by should be: Type in the VS version.